# Ignore null values when using SQL Server 2012's Last_Value() function

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have a table of values that look like this. It is populated with event data.

```
FldType Date                    Price   Size
--------------------------------------------
2       2012-08-22 00:02:01     9140    1048
0       2012-08-22 00:02:02     9140    77
1       2012-08-22 00:02:03     9150    281
2       2012-08-22 00:02:04     9140    1090
0       2012-08-22 00:02:05     9150    1
1       2012-08-22 00:02:06     9150    324
2       2012-08-22 00:02:07     9140    1063
```

I would like to track the lastest value for each of the 3 field types (0,1,2) so that the final output looks like this.

```
Date                Price0  Size0   Price1  Size1   Price2  Size2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2012-08-22 00:02:01  NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    9140    1048
2012-08-22 00:02:02  9140   77      NULL    NULL    9140    1048
2012-08-22 00:02:03  9140   77      9150    281     9140    1048
2012-08-22 00:02:04  9140   77      9150    281     9140    1090
2012-08-22 00:02:05  9150   1       9150    281     9140    1090
2012-08-22 00:02:06  9150   1       9150    324     9140    1090
2012-08-22 00:02:07  9150   1       9150    324     9140    1063
```

Unfortunately, it is not ignoring subsequent null values so I get this instead.

```
Date                Price0  Size0   Price1  Size1   Price2  Size2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2012-08-22 00:02:01  NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    9140    1048
2012-08-22 00:02:02  9140   77      NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
2012-08-22 00:02:03  NULL   NULL    9150    281     NULL    NULL
2012-08-22 00:02:04  NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    9140    1090
2012-08-22 00:02:05  9150   1       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
2012-08-22 00:02:06  NULL   NULL    9150    324     NULL    NULL    
2012-08-22 00:02:07  NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    9140    1063
```

My current query looks like this

```
SELECT [Date],
    LAST_VALUE(Price0) OVER (PARTITION BY FldType ORDER BY [Date] ) AS Price0,
    LAST_VALUE(Size0) OVER (PARTITION BY FldType ORDER BY [Date]) AS Size0,
    LAST_VALUE(Price1) OVER (PARTITION BY FldType ORDER BY [Date] ) AS Price1,
    LAST_VALUE(Size1) OVER (PARTITION BY FldType ORDER BY [Date]) AS Size1,
    LAST_VALUE(Price2) OVER (PARTITION BY FldType ORDER BY [Date] ) AS Price2,
    LAST_VALUE(Size2) OVER (PARTITION BY FldType ORDER BY [Date]) AS Size2
FROM ( 
SELECT FldType, [Date], Price, Size,
    CASE WHEN FldType = 0 THEN Price END as Price0,
    CASE WHEN FldType = 0 THEN Size END as Size0,
    CASE WHEN FldType = 1 THEN Price END as Price1,
    CASE WHEN FldType = 1 THEN Size END as Size1,
    CASE WHEN FldType = 2 THEN Price END as Price2,
    CASE WHEN FldType = 2 THEN Size END as Size2
FROM [RawData].[dbo].[Events]   
) as T1
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Is there some way to have SQL Server 2012 ignore null values when determining the lastest value? Or is there a better approach not using `Last_Value()` function?

To summarize I am trying to achieve two thing.

1. Split the `Price` and `Size` columns into 6 columns (2 columns x 3 field types)
2. Keep track of the latest value in each of these columns.

Any suggestions would be apprciated.

Comment: **SQL** = structured query language, the languate itself; **SQL 2012** = the 2012 standard for the SQL language (inexistant); SQL **Server** 2012 = the 2012 version of Microsoft's **SQL Server** product

Comment: @marc_S Good point!. Thanks for changing that!

Comment: Edited title to make clear that it was SQL Server 2012. This is important distinction because 1) Oracle's SQL does have an ignore nulls option and 2) In SQL Server 2012 there are 'ROWS' and 'RANGE' options that may be of some use in finding a solution

Comment: Well, the consensus amongst Stackers is that stuff like which exact version of SQL Server you're using belongs in the **tags** - not the title....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it with LAST_VALUE, unless you add a PIVOT maybe.

Also, you need to treat Size and Price separately because they come from different rows. So, this achieves what you want be breaking it down.

```
DECLARE @source TABLE (FldType int, DateCol DateTime, Price int, Size int);

INSERT @source VALUES
    (2, '2012-08-22 00:02:01', 9140, 1048),(0, '2012-08-22 00:02:02', 9140, 77),
    (1, '2012-08-22 00:02:03', 9150, 281),(2, '2012-08-22 00:02:04', 9140, 1090),
    (0, '2012-08-22 00:02:05', 9150, 1),(1, '2012-08-22 00:02:06', 9150, 324),
    (2, '2012-08-22 00:02:07', 9140, 1063);


SELECT
    S.DateCol, Xp0.Price0, Xs0.Size0, Xp1.Price1, Xs1.Size1, Xp2.Price2, Xs2.Size2
FROM
    @source S
    OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 S0.Price AS Price0 FROM @source S0 WHERE S0.FldType = 0 AND S0.DateCol <= S.DateCol ORDER BY S0.DateCol DESC) Xp0
    OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 S1.Price AS Price1 FROM @source S1 WHERE S1.FldType = 1 AND S1.DateCol <= S.DateCol ORDER BY S1.DateCol DESC) Xp1
    OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 S2.Price AS Price2 FROM @source S2 WHERE S2.FldType = 2 AND S2.DateCol <= S.DateCol ORDER BY S2.DateCol DESC) Xp2
    OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 S0.Size AS Size0 FROM @source S0 WHERE S0.FldType = 0 AND S0.DateCol <= S.DateCol ORDER BY S0.DateCol DESC) Xs0
    OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 S1.Size AS Size1 FROM @source S1 WHERE S1.FldType = 1 AND S1.DateCol <= S.DateCol ORDER BY S1.DateCol DESC) Xs1
    OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 S2.Size AS Size2 FROM @source S2 WHERE S2.FldType = 2 AND S2.DateCol <= S.DateCol ORDER BY S2.DateCol DESC) Xs2
ORDER BY
    DateCol;
```

The other way is to maintain a separate table via triggers or some ETL that does it the summary for you.

Comment: Thank you! This does indeed give me exactly what I need. I was not aware of the OUTER APPLY method. <- Learned something completely new too!!

Comment: @ChrisTarn, Essentially, you need `LAST_VALUE` with `IGNORE NULL` clause, but unfortunately SQL Server doesn't implement it (Oracle, for example, does). The `OUTER APPLY` approach may be quite expensive because of running the subquery for each row. Itzik Ben-Gan showed in his [The Last non NULL Puzzle](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle) how it could be done more efficiently.