# SQL Server: Create an optimized view that retrieve the most recent non null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, view

I've done this clearly not optimized view in SQL Server:

```
SELECT     ID, T_ID, SRNB, P_DATETIME,
                      (SELECT     TOP (1) COL_A
                        FROM          dbo.T_DETAIL AS T
                        WHERE      (T_ID = a.T_ID) AND (COL_A IS NOT NULL) AND (P_DATETIME <= a.P_DATETIME)
                        ORDER BY P_DATETIME DESC) AS COL_A, COL_A_MU,
                      (SELECT     TOP (1) COL_B
                        FROM          dbo.T_DETAIL AS T
                        WHERE      (T_ID = a.T_ID) AND (COL_B IS NOT NULL) AND (P_DATETIME <= a.P_DATETIME)
                        ORDER BY P_DATETIME DESC) AS COL_B, COL_B_MU,
--...for several columns
                      (SELECT     TOP (1) COL_Z
                        FROM          dbo.T_DETAIL AS T
                        WHERE      (T_ID = a.T_ID) AND (COL_Z > 0) AND (P_DATETIME <= a.P_DATETIME)
                        ORDER BY P_DATETIME DESC) AS COL_Z
FROM         dbo.T_DETAIL AS a
```

The aim of this view is to get from the table T_DETAIL the most recent value NOT NULL (or NOT 0 in some cases).

Example: T_DETAIL is

```
+-----+------+------+----------------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID  | T_ID | SRNB |   P_DATETIME   | COL_A | COL_B | COL_Z |
+-----+------+------+----------------+-------+-------+-------+
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:15 | 5     | NULL  | 10    |
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:16 | NULL  | 10    | NULL  |
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:17 | NULL  | 5     | 5     |
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:18 | 5     | NULL  | NULL  |
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:19 | NULL  | NULL  | 11    |
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:20 | 7     | NULL  | 10    |
+-----+------+------+----------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

in the view becomes like this:

```
+-----+------+------+----------------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID  | T_ID | SRNB |   P_DATETIME   | COL_A | COL_B | COL_Z |
+-----+------+------+----------------+-------+-------+-------+
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:15 | 5     | NULL  | 10    |
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:16 | 5     | 10    | 10    |
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:17 | 5     | 5     | 5     |
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:18 | 5     | 5     | 5     |
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:19 | 5     | 5     | 11    |
| xxx | aaa  | aaa  | 20131205 20:20 | 7     | 5     | 10    |
+-----+------+------+----------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The view works but is painfully slow. Where should I start optimizing it? I've tried to make it an indexed view but SQL Server Manager warned me that `ORDER BY` is only used with `TOP 1` for the retrieval of the most recent value. I think I should start from that, but how? Maybe using `MAX()` somewhere will be a better choice, but I don't want to add complexity and screw things up.

What path should I follow? Is there maybe a canonical way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: I don't understand you said `NOT NULL`, but you have a value `NULL` in the second example? I think that it is good to provide more information about the data itself. So may be there is a better way in general to achieve your goal.

Comment: The value in the second column is NULL because there isn't a value different from null available.
More data I think will be unuseful because I can't think of a better example to do.
Refrasing, what I need is a view that given a row with a timestamp and some other fields that can be NULL, have a row with the same timestamp and the most recent NON NULL field available, or NULL if there are none.

Comment: I understand, an one more detail `COL_A_MU` and `COL_B_MU` are not visible in the example and I don't see `COL_Z_MU` in the script?

Comment: These colums are taken from T_DETAIL. They are fixed values and we don't need calculation on them. I could have omitted them.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  I think that 2012 has a better way to optimize this.

Comment: Try this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953708/ignore-null-values-when-using-sql-server-2012s-last-value-function  It's probably about as good an answer as you can get for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For each `COL_X` subquery, instead of:

```
(SELECT     TOP (1) COL_A
 FROM          dbo.T_DETAIL AS T
 WHERE      (T_ID = a.T_ID) AND (COL_A IS NOT NULL) AND (P_DATETIME <= a.P_DATETIME)
 ORDER BY P_DATETIME DESC) AS COL_A, COL_A_MU
```

try this:

```
  (SELECT     COL_A
   FROM       dbo.T_DETAIL AS T
   WHERE      T_ID = a.T_ID
   AND        P_DATETIME =    
     (select  max(P_DATETIME) 
      FROM    dbo.T_DETAIL AS T2
      WHERE   T_ID = a.T_ID AND COL_A IS NOT NULL
      AND     P_DATETIME <= a.P_DATETIME
     )
   ) AS COL_A,
```

I'm not able to test it, but I hope this is of some help.

For better performance, it may help to have an index on `T_ID` (and other key columns if they are used in the joins) and `P_DATETIME` in the same index.

Comment: I'm not able to try that right away, I'll let you know on monday.

Answer (score 0):

"the most recent value"

is it possible to introduce a datetime column (with default value) to store created datetime?

if yes, you can then create index using this datetime (trial with its sorting order) for speedy "recent value" sorting, then follow by the A B Z columns in the index.
and use this index in your query

Comment: In this case the most recent value is the one with most near `P_DATETIME`. So in this case yes, this is a solution, but brung the view select execution from 7 seconds to 5 seconds. I think my view definition was wrong (or overly complex) from the beginning and beside this optimization (that works) we should also make other changes.

Comment: try tackle the issue at 1 table, as all the tables structure are same. look at how sql analyst performing it index picking. try force your query to use the specific query with query hint. if you resolve this issue at 1 table, it should help at the view performance